# Swift ObjectMapper keeps returning ambiguous without more context

Tags: arrays, swift, objectmapper

I am attempting to use Swift 3 with ([ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/)) to map a `players` array from a given JSON response on a cut-down class object called "Player"; but am finding it difficult to map it.

```
// Sample JSON
{
    "_meta": {
        ...
    },
    "fixtures": [{
        ...
    }],
    "players": [{
        "name": "Smith",
        "id": "15475-9524",
    }]
}
```

However, I am finding it hard to get it to understand how to make it map properly as it always complains that it needs more context.

I am wanting my JSON consumer to get me the list of players then map all the players using Object Mapper into an array.

When I use

`var players : Array<Player> = Mapper<Player>().mapArray(JSONArray: res)`

It complains

`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

My class is as follows

```
class Player: NSObject, Mappable {
    var name: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {
        super.init()
    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name    <- map["name"]
    }
}
```

I am using AlamoFire to consume the JSON.

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
    response in

    switch response.result {

    case .success(let JSON):

        guard let res = JSON as? [String:Any] else {
            print ("Can't do this")
            return
        }

        var players : Array<Player> = Mapper<Player>().mapArray(JSONArray: res)

print (players)

    break

    case .failure(let error):
        print("** Request failed with error: \(error) **")
        break
    }
```

I don't quite understand how to use the ObjectMapper on the array I'm wanting to fetch.

Any assistance on this would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing JSON Dictionary with Player's array.

Try this:

```
    guard let res = JSON as? [String:Any] else {
        print ("res:Can't do this")
        return
    }

    guard let json_players = res["players"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
        print ("json_players:Can't do this")
        return
    }

    var players : Array<Player> = Mapper<Player>().mapArray(JSONArray: json_players)
```

Comment: Okay, will do.  I've not used ObjectMapper before and wanted to give it a go as I've always done the parsing manually

Comment: It worked, many thanks; although it was complaining about an optional value not being unwrapped; so changed it to `let players : Array<Player> = Mapper<Player>().mapArray(JSONArray: json_players)!`